# JMeter with 20000 threads and multi-home network

Tags: jmeter, apache-httpclient-4.x

In the scenario where you're running a single Linux instance of jmeter with 20000 threads and 4 ip addresses, would jmeter (HttpClient4) use all ports in all 4 IP addresses for http connections, or is it restricted to one IP choosen by jmeter (In Linux machine) ?

Thanks

Comment: The 4 IPs are in different computer per port? Can you add more details?

Comment: 4 IPs in the same Instance.. OS is Linux

Answer (score 0):

JMeter will stick to a single IP address by default, if you want to distribute the outgoing connections between all 4 IP addresses you will need to put them into a CSV file and use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to read it so each thread (virtual user) would choose a new source address on each iteration.

The source IP address can be set at "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults))

[image]

See [Using IP Spoofing to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter) article for more information.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, what if you run with 2000 vusers, and keep alive off, then TCP connections will run out of ports from one IP, will it use a second IP for outgoing connections?